# Browser's back button taking too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add a page in my NextJS project which contains a form for posting some information. This page is only accessible by clicking an "add new" bootstrap button, wrapped in a Link tag. The redirect goes fine but when I click on the browser's back button it takes like 2 min to go back to the homepage (where is the "add new" button).

this is my Package.json:

```
{
    "name": "FrontEnd",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
        "next": "^9.1.1",
        "react": "^16.10.2",
        "react-calendar": "^2.19.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.10.2"
    }
}
```

My 'Home' page:

```
const Index = (props) => (
<Layout>
    <ul>
        {props.reservas.map(reserva => (
            <li>
                <ReservaPreview props={reserva.props}/>
            </li>
        ))}

        <li><AgregarReservaBoton /></li>

    </ul>
</Layout>
);
```

My 'Bootstrap button':

```
class AgregarReservaBoton extends Component {


    render() {

        return (
        <div>
            <Link href='/nuevaReserva'>
                <button type="button"></button>
            </Link>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My 'Redirect' page:

```
const NuevaReserva = (props) => (
    <div>
        <Layout>
            <AgregarReservaForm />
        </Layout>
    </div>
)
```

Imports and Exports done.

Browser's back button working fine.

Comment: Huh... this is a very strange problem... are you able to create an [mcve] for the purposes of helping the community solve your issue?

Comment: think i did it, ty for answering